# stdin takes string in python2.7 but only takes bytes in python3.4

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to port a module from python2.7 to python3.4. In python2.7 (code below) the classifier takes a string object (i) and returns output in a matter of milliseconds read from stdout.

However when I change the code to python3.4 stdin complains it only takes bytes input. Converting the input (i) to bytes using

```
i = i.encode('utf-8)
```

works but no output can be read from stdout. Why?

Unfortunately I am not familiar with the code in tweets.annotated.csv.model

```
class CapClassifier:
    def __init__(self, model='%s/data/cap2/tweets.annotated.csv.model' % (BASE_DIR)):
        self.capClassifier = subprocess.Popen('%s/python/cap/cap_classify %s/data/cap2/tweets.annotated.csv.model' % (BASE_DIR, BASE_DIR),
                                          shell=True,
                                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.fe = FeatureExtractor('%s/data/cap2/tweets_cap.vocab' % (BASE_DIR))

    def Classify(self, words):
        i = "%s\n" % self.fe.Extract(' '.join(words))
        self.capClassifier.stdin.write(i)
        (features, prediction) = self.capClassifier.stdout.readline().rstrip('\n').split('\t')
        return float(prediction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to add `universal_newlines=True` to accept strings as stated in Robin's answer and add `self.capClassifier.stdin.flush()` after the `write`-statement for results to return

Answer (score 0):

> Popen.stdin
>
> If the stdin argument was PIPE, this attribute is a writeable stream object as returned by open(). If the universal_newlines argument was True, the stream is a text stream, otherwise it is a byte stream. If the stdin argument was not PIPE, this attribute is None.

May this quote from the python documentation helps. Add `universal_newlines=True` to the subprocess.Popen constructor.

Comment: The error (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str') is now gone, however I still do not obtain output from stdout